# Weird query plan change based on the limit

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a PostgreSQL server ver. 15.4 and I have a query like the below :

```sql
SELECT i."Id"
FROM "InventoryItems"                                  i
         INNER JOIN "Products"                         p ON i."ProductBaseId" = p."Id"
         INNER JOIN (SELECT "CustomerMarketPlaceId", PLAINTO_TSQUERY('english', "Keyword") "Keyword"
                     FROM "RestrictedKeywords"
                     WHERE "CustomerMarketPlaceId" = 19100
                     LIMIT 158
                     ) z
                    ON z."CustomerMarketPlaceId" = i."CustomerMarketPlaceId"

WHERE i."CustomerMarketPlaceId" = 19100
  AND i."Status" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7)
  AND TO_TSVECTOR('english', COALESCE(p."Title", '')) @@ z."Keyword";
```

Please note the weird number **158** in the subquery. This produces the below execution plan which is cool, all using indexes, index-only scans, heap scans, etc.

```
Hash Join  (cost=1704.06..102240.40 rows=5758 width=8)
  Hash Cond: (p.""Id"" = i.""ProductBaseId"")"
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=59.43..97792.89 rows=244027 width=8)
        ->  Subquery Scan on z  (cost=0.29..45.30 rows=79 width=36)
              Filter: (z.""CustomerMarketPlaceId"" = 19100)"
              ->  Limit  (cost=0.29..43.32 rows=158 width=36)
                    ->  Index Only Scan using ""IX_RestrictedKeywords_CustomerMarketPlaceId"" on ""RestrictedKeywords""  (cost=0.29..3199.81 rows=11747 width=36)"
                          Index Cond: (""CustomerMarketPlaceId"" = 19100)"
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on ""Products"" p  (cost=59.14..1206.42 rows=3089 width=132)"
              Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (COALESCE(""Title"", ''::character varying))::text) @@ z.""Keyword"")"
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ""IX_Products_Title""  (cost=0.00..58.37 rows=3089 width=0)"
                    Index Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (COALESCE(""Title"", ''::character varying))::text) @@ z.""Keyword"")"
  ->  Hash  (cost=1462.43..1462.43 rows=14576 width=16)
        ->  Index Scan using ""IX_InventoryItems_CustomerMarketPlaceId_Status"" on ""InventoryItems"" i  (cost=0.29..1462.43 rows=14576 width=16)"
              Index Cond: ((""CustomerMarketPlaceId"" = 19100) AND (""Status"" = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,6,7}'::integer[])))"
```

But when I change that magic number to **159** the below query plan comes up :

```
Hash Join  (cost=50296.29..104375.05 rows=6195 width=8)
  Hash Cond: (i.""ProductBaseId"" = p.""Id"")"
  Join Filter: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (COALESCE(p.""Title"", ''::character varying))::text) @@ z.""Keyword"")"
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.58..16998.07 rows=1238960 width=44)
        ->  Index Scan using ""IX_InventoryItems_CustomerMarketPlaceId_Status"" on ""InventoryItems"" i  (cost=0.29..1462.43 rows=14576 width=16)"
              Index Cond: ((""CustomerMarketPlaceId"" = 19100) AND (""Status"" = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,6,7}'::integer[])))"
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.29..48.86 rows=85 width=36)
              ->  Subquery Scan on z  (cost=0.29..48.43 rows=85 width=36)
                    Filter: (z.""CustomerMarketPlaceId"" = 19100)"
                    ->  Limit  (cost=0.29..46.32 rows=169 width=36)
                          ->  Index Only Scan using ""IX_RestrictedKeywords_CustomerMarketPlaceId"" on ""RestrictedKeywords""  (cost=0.29..3199.81 rows=11747 width=36)"
                                Index Cond: (""CustomerMarketPlaceId"" = 19100)"
  ->  Hash  (cost=30535.76..30535.76 rows=616876 width=132)
        ->  Seq Scan on ""Products"" p  (cost=0.00..30535.76 rows=616876 width=132)"
```

Suddenly it starts to think that full scanning of the `Products` table will perform better in theory but in practice, the query slows down 100x (or maybe more). I have tried to change
`default_statistics_target` to a larger number and re-analyzing the related tables in the query didn't change the result. I have tried this in both production and test environments the only difference is the limit as the production environment has more RAM to work with. What is causing PostgreSQL to change its mind? (I guess it thinks the query won't fit into memory???) And why it is selecting a drastically worse execution plan? Even if it doesn't use the `gin` index, the query still can be filtered over `"InventoryItems"("CustomerMarketPlaceId","Status")` index.

I don't know if it helps but the index used in the query is like the one below:

```
CREATE INDEX "IX_Products_Title"
    ON "Products" USING gin (TO_TSVECTOR('english'::REGCONFIG, COALESCE("Title", ''::CHARACTER VARYING)::TEXT));
```

If I refactor the same query (even if I remove the limit in the subquery) like the one below it will pick a better execution plan, and indeed result in a much faster query

```
SELECT i."Id"
FROM "InventoryItems"                                  i
         INNER JOIN "Products"                         p ON i."ProductBaseId" = p."Id"
         INNER JOIN (SELECT "CustomerMarketPlaceId", PLAINTO_TSQUERY('english', "Keyword") "Keyword"
                     FROM "RestrictedKeywords"
                    -- WHERE "CustomerMarketPlaceId" = 19100 
                    --- LIMIT 500
                     ) z
                    ON  TO_TSVECTOR('english', COALESCE(p."Title", '')) @@ z."Keyword" z."CustomerMarketPlaceId" = i."CustomerMarketPlaceId" 

WHERE i."CustomerMarketPlaceId" = 19100
  AND i."Status" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7)
  AND TO_TSVECTOR('english', COALESCE(p."Title", '')) @@ z."Keyword"; -- <-- removing this condition will cause full scans
```

Produces this execution plan :

```
Hash Join  (cost=1646.19..238317.48 rows=4281 width=8)
  Hash Cond: (p.""Id"" = i.""ProductBaseId"")"
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.56..234592.40 rows=181124 width=4)
        ->  Index Only Scan using ""IX_RestrictedKeywords_CustomerMarketPlaceId"" on ""RestrictedKeywords""  (cost=0.29..263.06 rows=11747 width=11)"
              Index Cond: (""CustomerMarketPlaceId"" = 19100)"
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on ""Products"" p  (cost=1.28..19.80 rows=15 width=132)"
              Recheck Cond: ((to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (COALESCE(""Title"", ''::character varying))::text) @@ plainto_tsquery('english'::regconfig, (""RestrictedKeywords"".""Keyword"")::text)) AND (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (COALESCE(""Title"", ''::character varying))::text) @@ plainto_tsquery('english'::regconfig, (""RestrictedKeywords"".""Keyword"")::text)))"
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ""IX_Products_Title""  (cost=0.00..1.27 rows=15 width=0)"
                    Index Cond: ((to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (COALESCE(""Title"", ''::character varying))::text) @@ plainto_tsquery('english'::regconfig, (""RestrictedKeywords"".""Keyword"")::text)) AND (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (COALESCE(""Title"", ''::character varying))::text) @@ plainto_tsquery('english'::regconfig, (""RestrictedKeywords"".""Keyword"")::text)))"
  ->  Hash  (cost=1462.43..1462.43 rows=14576 width=12)
        ->  Index Scan using ""IX_InventoryItems_CustomerMarketPlaceId_Status"" on ""InventoryItems"" i  (cost=0.29..1462.43 rows=14576 width=12)"
              Index Cond: ((""CustomerMarketPlaceId"" = 19100) AND (""Status"" = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,6,7}'::integer[])))"
```

Any explanations to help me understand these execution plan selections will be much appreciated.

**Edit:** I have added `explain (analyze,buffers)` output of the first two limit queries as requested in the comment:

```
Hash Join  (cost=1684.53..99640.82 rows=5780 width=8) (actual time=15.972..333.366 rows=1953 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (p.""Id"" = i.""ProductBaseId"")"
  Buffers: shared hit=41110 dirtied=1513
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=34.49..95801.34 rows=243616 width=8) (actual time=0.273..316.567 rows=47020 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=39674 dirtied=1513
        ->  Subquery Scan on z  (cost=0.29..45.30 rows=79 width=36) (actual time=0.050..0.566 rows=158 loops=1)
              Filter: (z.""CustomerMarketPlaceId"" = 19100)"
              Buffers: shared hit=4
              ->  Limit  (cost=0.29..43.32 rows=158 width=36) (actual time=0.049..0.544 rows=158 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=4
                    ->  Index Only Scan using ""IX_RestrictedKeywords_CustomerMarketPlaceId"" on ""RestrictedKeywords""  (cost=0.29..3199.81 rows=11747 width=36) (actual time=0.048..0.528 rows=158 loops=1)"
                          Index Cond: (""CustomerMarketPlaceId"" = 19100)"
                          Heap Fetches: 0
                          Buffers: shared hit=4
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on ""Products"" p  (cost=34.20..1181.26 rows=3084 width=132) (actual time=0.127..1.960 rows=298 loops=158)"
              Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (COALESCE(""Title"", ''::character varying))::text) @@ z.""Keyword"")"
              Heap Blocks: exact=37818
              Buffers: shared hit=39670 dirtied=1513
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ""IX_Products_Title""  (cost=0.00..33.43 rows=3084 width=0) (actual time=0.096..0.096 rows=298 loops=158)"
                    Index Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (COALESCE(""Title"", ''::character varying))::text) @@ z.""Keyword"")"
                    Buffers: shared hit=1803
  ->  Hash  (cost=1467.12..1467.12 rows=14634 width=16) (actual time=11.340..11.340 rows=19978 loops=1)
        Buckets: 32768 (originally 16384)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1193kB
        Buffers: shared hit=1436
        ->  Index Scan using ""IX_InventoryItems_CustomerMarketPlaceId_Status"" on ""InventoryItems"" i  (cost=0.29..1467.12 rows=14634 width=16) (actual time=0.012..8.048 rows=19978 loops=1)"
              Index Cond: ((""CustomerMarketPlaceId"" = 19100) AND (""Status"" = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,6,7}'::integer[])))"
              Buffers: shared hit=1436
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=29
Planning Time: 0.753 ms
Execution Time: 333.540 ms
```

```
Hash Join  (cost=50366.43..107003.29 rows=6585 width=8) (actual time=414.038..86828.819 rows=2373 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (i.""ProductBaseId"" = p.""Id"")"
  Join Filter: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (COALESCE(p.""Title"", ''::character varying))::text) @@ z.""Keyword"")"
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 3593667
  Buffers: shared hit=25883 dirtied=267, temp read=29576 written=29576"
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.58..17982.15 rows=1317060 width=44) (actual time=0.045..591.422 rows=3596040 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=1440
        ->  Index Scan using ""IX_InventoryItems_CustomerMarketPlaceId_Status"" on ""InventoryItems"" i  (cost=0.29..1467.12 rows=14634 width=16) (actual time=0.013..7.770 rows=19978 loops=1)"
              Index Cond: ((""CustomerMarketPlaceId"" = 19100) AND (""Status"" = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,6,7}'::integer[])))"
              Buffers: shared hit=1436
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.29..52.01 rows=90 width=36) (actual time=0.000..0.008 rows=180 loops=19978)
              Buffers: shared hit=4
              ->  Subquery Scan on z  (cost=0.29..51.56 rows=90 width=36) (actual time=0.029..0.531 rows=180 loops=1)
                    Filter: (z.""CustomerMarketPlaceId"" = 19100)"
                    Buffers: shared hit=4
                    ->  Limit  (cost=0.29..49.31 rows=180 width=36) (actual time=0.028..0.507 rows=180 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=4
                          ->  Index Only Scan using ""IX_RestrictedKeywords_CustomerMarketPlaceId"" on ""RestrictedKeywords""  (cost=0.29..3199.81 rows=11747 width=36) (actual time=0.028..0.491 rows=180 loops=1)"
                                Index Cond: (""CustomerMarketPlaceId"" = 19100)"
                                Heap Fetches: 0
                                Buffers: shared hit=4
  ->  Hash  (cost=30610.49..30610.49 rows=616749 width=132) (actual time=349.356..349.356 rows=616749 loops=1)
        Buckets: 524288  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 26496kB
        Buffers: shared hit=24443 dirtied=267, temp written=7668"
        ->  Seq Scan on ""Products"" p  (cost=0.00..30610.49 rows=616749 width=132) (actual time=0.004..178.437 rows=616749 loops=1)"
              Buffers: shared hit=24443 dirtied=267
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=29
Planning Time: 0.423 ms
Execution Time: 86829.206 ms
```

Comment: "Why does it switch?" is easy to answer, because it thinks it will be faster with the switch.  "Why it is wrong about that?" is harder, and we would need to see at least `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for both LIMITs to have much hope of answering it.

Comment: @jjanes I have edited the question.

Comment: Try if reducing `random_page_cost` makes a difference. Try increasing `work_mem` until no more temp files are used.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks for the input, I have tried to set random_page_cost to 0.1 (from 1.1) and work_mem to 4GB (from 24mb). Reducing the random page cost lower than seq. cost indeed worked, it picked an index (PK_Products) but the execution time didn't change it is still 90~ in seconds. The query below the threshold runs in 300ms with the old setup.

Comment: Don't set `random_page_cost` much lower than `seq_page_cost`. I have no more ideas.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe :)= They were just experiments on the test environment thanks for the help btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like essentially all the time of the slow plan is going to the computation of to_tsvector.  The procost of that function is 100, so it is "known" to be slow, but not nearly as slow as it actually is.  The true cost of that function depends on how long the input string is, so it is hard to come up with a universal estimate.  I would say that 1000 is better starting point than 100, but is probably still too low.  You can bump up the cost by doing:

```
alter function to_tsvector ( regconfig, text) cost 1000;
```

But note that this change will not survive a dump/restore or an pg_upgrade, so you would need to repeat it.

If you want a more principled approach, you could compare

```
explain analyze select sum(length(COALESCE(p."Title", ''))) from products p
```

to

```
explain analyze select sum(length(TO_TSVECTOR('english', COALESCE(p."Title", '')))) from products p;
```

And compare the ratio of the cost estimates to the ratio of the actual timings.  Then you would want to adjust the procost until those ratios were similar to each other.  However, this would be tailored specifically to the contents of the "Title" column.  If you have other uses of to_tsvector in your system, it might not be suitable for them.

There are also other things going on.  The row estimates are also off, like 1317060 vs 3596040, and off in a direction which exacerbates the to_tsvector estimation problem.  I think they are relatively minor compared to the mis-costing of to_tsvector, but might still be worth addressing.

Comment: Assigning cost to a function is not something that is easily discoverable, very much appreciated.